# Why can “39” be pronounced as 「ミク」？

Tags: pronunciation, counters

I was recently listening to someone talk about a game called “初音ミク Project DIVA MEGA39’s”. The English localization is changed to “MEGAMIX”.

They actually noted that 3 and 9 can be pronounced as ミ and ク respectively, but I’ve never heard these numbers pronounced this way.

What kind of reading is this to produce those sounds?